# simple teclado numérico para Android

Tags: python, android, qpython

Tengo una aplicación en lenguaje python que básicamente se anotan números y ella suma o resta dichos valores y muestra los resultados en pantalla, es bien básica, la tengo instalada en mi teléfono Android, tengo instalado Qpython que me permite correr esta aplicación en mi móvil, pero cuando le doy "play" a la aplicación se abre todo el teclado alfanumérico completo, me gustaría saber si existe alguna manera para que cuando esté en esta app se abra un teclado numérico, como los de principio de los Android (adjunto imagen) donde solo se mostraban los números(0 al 9), "enter" y "delete".
Adjunto imagen de ejemplo del teclado que busco y adjunto código de python, agradezco cualquier ayuda.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
#-*-coding:utf8-*-
dictAAVariation = {
  '0': 1.00,
  '1': 1.00,
  '2': 1.00,
  '3': 1.00,
  '4': 1.00,
  '5': -1.00,
  '6': -1.00,
  '7': -1.00,
  '8': -1.00,
  '9': -1.00
}

class Game(object):
    def __init__(self, num_cards):
        self.num_cards=num_cards
        n=num_cards/13
    
        self.deck = {'1':n , '2':n, '3':n, '4':n, '5':n, '6':n, '7':n, '8':n, '9':n, '0':n}

        if num_cards==312:
            self.counter = 0.00
        else:
            self.counter = 0.00

    def AA_predict(self, str_numbers):
        result = 0
        for digit in str_numbers:
            if digit >= '0' and digit <= '9':
               if self.deck[digit] > 0:
                 result += dictAAVariation[digit]                
                self.deck[digit] -= 1
        self.counter += result
        return result

def getNumCards():
  num=0
  print ("")
  while True:
    num=int(raw_input("Cantidad de Cartas es 312:"))
    print("")
    if num==312:
      break
  return num

def main():
    num_cards=getNumCards()
    game=Game(num_cards)
    while True:
      AA_predict=XX_predict=YY_predict=raw_input("introduzca:")
      if AA_predict=='quit' or AA_predict=='exit':
        break

      X1 = game.AA_predict(AA_predict)
      X2 = game.counter   
 
      print("Valor en Curso: %f" % float(X1))
      print("Contador: %f\n" % float(X2))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```